# Use Office 365 API to create a public read-only calendar Web page on a blog

Tags: calendar, office365

I am using Office 365 to manage my calendars. I would just like to publish one of my calendars to my blog. Also, I would like to fully control the style of the calendar.  I can enter API URLs into the browser and basic authentication to access my own calendars. So, I could do that from the server to build my calendar page using a server side http client. In this case, I don't really need the full power of OAuth2, which is mainly for letting multiple visitors manage their own content on a third-party site.

It would be nice if Microsoft's Office365 libraries would handle this scenario. It could also include a step where I register for a keys similar to the way Google Maps does. Or do they offer this already?

Does anyone know what steps to take so my scenario would work? Also, would I run up against any usage limits for a popular blog?

Answer (score 1):

While the API is supporting Basic at the moment, that will eventually go away. You can definitely make your scenario work using the authorization code grant flow that's in place today, but it sounds like you may be more interested in the client credential flow which we are going to be releasing support for soon. That would allow you as the administrator of your Office 365 organization to authorize an app to access calendars in your organization without requiring user sign-in.

You register for client IDs and client secrets [via Azure AD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/HowTo/add-common-consent-manually#bk_ManuallyRegisterWebApp).

Azure AD is included with Office 365, and registering apps doesn't include any additional paid Azure services.

The client IDs and secrets obtained with the Visual Studio tool are permanent, and not just for debugging. Can you point me at the documentation that said otherwise so I can get it corrected? :)

Comment: I think Azure AD requires the Premium subscription, is that correct?

Comment: I saw the Visual Studio Office365 extension gets the client id and secret, but it appears from the documentation that this is a temporary key that only works for testing in the Visual Studio debugger. For me, I tried passing in a UserCredential but the asynchronous authentication function appeared to hang.

Comment: If I can get my scenario to work using the authorization code grant flow that's in place today then I would definitely be happy to do that. Currently I don't have the Premium subscription, though. Is that going to be a problem? If not, I wonder what I need to do to get my scenario to work. Any pointers are appreciated.

Comment: What type of subscription do you have? When you say "Premium", are you referring to the "Azure Active Directory Premium" subscription? It is NOT required.

Comment: I have the Office 365 Small Business (there is an Office 365 Small Business Premium).

Comment: I believe you should still be able to register apps in Azure AD. You can access the Azure AD portal right from your Office 365 subscription. Check this blog post and make sure you see Azure AD in your Admin menu. http://chakkaradeep.com/index.php/access-azure-active-directory-portal-from-your-office-365-subscription/

Comment: Thank you for your help. It looks like the blog post doesn't check for Office 365 Small Business subscriptions, and according to the docs it looks like the Premium subscription will have the Azure AD admin option.

Comment: Let me see if I can get verification on the Small Business subscription. I suspect it should work, but I'm not 100% clear on all of the differences between the subscription types. Stay tuned!